# how to calculate this convolution:

Tags: calculus, integration

having problems with the different sections:
$$x(t)=h(t)=u(t)-u(t-T) \\where \ \   u(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $t \ge0$} \\
0, & \text{if $t<0$}  \\
\end{cases}\\y(t)=(x*h)(t)=?$$
I'm not sure about the different domains of the integration

Comment: What is $u(t)$  and $t$ ?

Comment: u(t)= 1, t>0 and 0 else

Comment: That function looks a little funny. Is it possible that $u(t) - (t-T)$ is really $u(t) - u(t-T)$ and you copied it down incorrectly? I'm also a little surprised that the problem bothers to give two names $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ to the same function.

Comment: you are correct... I've fixed it

Answer (score 1):

$\int^{+\infty}_{0}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau=\int^{+\infty}_{0}(u(\tau)-u(\tau-T))h(t-\tau)d\tau=\int^{T}_{0}h(t-\tau)d\tau=\int^{T}_{0}u(t-\tau)-u(t-\tau-T)d\tau=$

$=\int^{T}_{0}u(t-\tau)d\tau - \int^{T}_{0}u(t-\tau-T)d\tau=$

now insert substitution: $x=t-\tau$, take care about integration bounds:

$=-\int^{t-T}_{t}u(x)dx + \int^{t-T}_{t}u(x-T)dx=-\int^{t-T}_{t}u(x)-u(x-T)dx=-(x-(x-T))|^{t-T}_t=-T(t-T-t)=T^2$

Maybe something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Your function is basically a rectangular pulse of amplitude $1$ from $t=0$ to $t=T$.

My understanding is that you want to convolve this function with itself ($y=(x*h)(t))$,where $x(t)=h(t)$).

Formally you wish to calculate

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\\=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[u(\tau)-u(\tau-T)][u(t-\tau)-u(t-\tau-T)]d\tau$$

An easier method is to visually represent the convolution process, by sliding the time reversed rectangular pulse from time $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, multiplying with the rectangular pulse fixed from time $0$ to $T$ and adding up the area, as illustrated below.

Note that the result will be non-zero for only when the pulses overlap, which occurs for time shifts between $-T$ and $T$ - when the pulse overlap, the product is simply $1$, so that the integral is simply $t_{upper}-t_{lower}$, the limits of the overlap.

[image]

The result is a triangular function, where

$$y(t)=t+T,-T\leq t <0\\y(t)=T-t,0\leq t <T$$

Comment: but what about negative T?

Comment: For negative $T$, you will have a pulse of amplitude $-1$ from $T$ to $0$. Convolving this pulse with itself, you will still end up with the same result as $-1\times -1=+1$.